# C# Get an object which is a property and execute a method in the object from a string value

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, properties, invoke

I have a class that have objects that are properties. Each of these objects has methods in them. From a string value/ variable I would like to get this property which is an object and execute its method.

```
var property = this.GetType().GetProperty( "SomePropertyObject" );
MethodInfo getMethod = property.GetMethod;
var obj = getMethod.Invoke......
var runMethod = obj.GetType().GetMethod( "SomeMethod" );
runMethod.Invoke(obj, new object[] { value1 } );
```

The problem is that when I get the property I only have the get and set methods to work with. If I can get the object via the get method, I can run the objects methods. Please can you tell me if this is possible and how do I go about doing it?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Basically I want to add auditing to my entity framework DbContext class. I have successfully created a single table audit for smaller projects but now I want to create per table auditing using reflection. I am able to create an audit model which is the same as its respective Model with an AuditId and Action (update, add, soft delete, etc). I use reflection to transfer the property values between the Model and the ModelAudit.

I would like to change my current switch statement that adds the ModelAudit to the respective DbSet collection.

```
private void SaveAudit( DbEntityEntry entry )
    {
        try
        {
            var name = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
            var space = entry.Entity.GetType().Namespace;
            var type = Type.GetType( string.Format( "{0}.Audits.{1}Audit", space, name ) );

            object audit = null;

            if ( type != null )
            {
                audit = Activator.CreateInstance( type );

                var props =
                    entry.Entity.GetType()
                        .GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy );

                audit.GetType().GetProperty( "Action" ).SetValue( audit, entry.State.ToString() );

                foreach ( var prop in props )
                {
                    if ( prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead )
                        switch ( prop.PropertyType.ToString() )
                        {
                            case "System.String":
                            case "System.string":
                            case "System.Int32":
                            case "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]":
                            case "System.Int64":
                            case "System.bool":
                            case "System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]":
                            case "System.DateTime":
                            case "System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]":
                                audit.GetType().GetProperty( prop.Name ).SetValue( audit, prop.GetValue( entry.Entity ) );
                                break;
                        }
                }

                // TODO: Replace with reflection.
                if ( !entry.State.ToString().Equals( "Unchanged" ) )
                {
                    switch ( name )
                    {
                        case "Account":
                            AccountAudits.Add( ( AccountAudit ) audit );
```

Comment: Can you show an example object?

Comment: Given that you are using `this`, why not just call `this.SomePropertyObject.SomeMethod(value1);`. You may need to give a better example if my comment does not apply to your issue

Comment: I hope my edit explains my situation a little better....

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could do the following:

```
public static object RunMethod(object o, string propertyName, string methodName, object[] methodArguments = null)
{
    var properyInfo = o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)

    if (properyInfo == null)
        //No such property, bail out appropiately

    var invokeTarget = properyInfo.GetValue(o);

    if (invokeTarget == null)
        //Property returned null, bail out appropiately

    var argumentTypes = methodArguments == null ? Enumerable.Empty<Type>() : methodArguments.Select(a => a.GetType());
    var methodInfo = invokeTarget.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, argumentTypes.ToArray());

    if (methodInfo == null)
       //No such method, bail out appropiately

    return methodInfo.Invoke(invokeTarget, methodArguments);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but I don't have a handle on the object, as the object is instantiated as a property when the class is instantiated.

Comment: @JayKayOf4 I don't follow you. I'm getting the instance through the property. Maybe using `o` is confusing you, it's really `this` based on your example.

Comment: I have edited my initial post, I hope that it explains my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with Reflection and can be done with something in the fashion of:

```
Type type = Assembly.GetType(some_type);
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(name_of_method);
ParameterInfo[] parameters = method?.GetParameters();
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);

var result = method.Invoke(instance, parameters);
```

This isn't tested, but I believe this is the general approach to the answer you're seeking.